# Filter nested object by keys using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have a nested object like this-

```
data = [{ 'title': 'Hey',
   'foo': 2,
   'bar': 3
 }, {
  'title': 'Sup',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
 }, {
  'title': 'Remove',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
}]
```

I want to filter this by the following array of titles(so if any title starts with any of these then i want that object)-

```
const filterTitles = ['He', 'Su']
```

So end result should be-

```
filteredData = [{ 'title': 'Hey',
   'foo': 2,
   'bar': 3
 }, {
  'title': 'Sup',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
 }]
```

This is what I did -

```
filteredData = _.map(data, section => 
    _.pick(section,val => 
      _.some(filterTitles, title => 
        _.startsWith(val, title)
        )
      )
  );
```

This filters it but just returns me an array of titles like this -

```
filteredData = ['Hey', 'Sup']
```

How do I get the array of filtered objects instead of array of filtered titles?
BTW I'm using lodash 3.10

Comment: Can `filterTitles` contain different length strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var data = [{
  'title': 'Hey',
  'foo': 2,
  'bar': 3
}, {
  'title': 'Sup',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
}, {
  'title': 'Remove',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
}]
const filterTitles = ['Hey', 'Sup'];

var result = data.filter(function(o) {
  return filterTitles.includes(o.title);
});

console.log(result)
```

Update: To filter objects in array whose title starts with element in `filterTitles` array you can use `filter()`, `some()` and `startsWith()`

```js
var data = [{
  'title': 'Hey',
  'foo': 2,
  'bar': 3
}, {
  'title': 'Sup',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
}, {
  'title': 'Remove',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
}]
const filterTitles = ['He', 'Su']

var result = data.filter(function(o) {
  return filterTitles.some(function(e) {
    return o.title.startsWith(e);
  })
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear in my question but I want to filter it by titles that startWith filterTitles array. I updated the question, how can i incorporate that when using your solution. Thanks

Comment: no, the length of titles in the object and filterTitles array is arbitrary. :(

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for ^

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows even if the keys are in different length. This is in fact a code for elastic search.

```js
var  data = [{ 'title': 'Hello',
   'foo': 2,
   'bar': 3
 }, {
  'title': 'Support',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
 }, {
  'title': 'Remove',
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4
}],

    keys = ["he","sup"],
filtered = keys.reduce((res,k) => res.concat(data.filter(o => o.title.slice(0,k.length).toLowerCase() === k.toLowerCase())),[]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in lodash.

```js
var data = [{ 'title': 'Hey', 'foo': 2,   'bar': 3 }, {  'title': 'Sup',  'foo': 3,  'bar': 4 }, {  'title': 'Remove',  'foo': 3,  'bar': 4}],
    filterTitles = ['He', 'Su'],
    result = _.filter(data, o => 
        _.some(filterTitles, title => _.startsWith(o.title, title)));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```